# Algolia search with Wordpress plugin showing code

Tags: wordpress, search, algolia

Using the Algolia wordpress plugin. Only issue is when you commence searching via a letter or two it brings up some sort of page design meta/code.

Demonstrated in this video here: https://www.opentest.co/share/6bb58c20893911e69225c7c933a8d325

Latest (4.6.1) Wordpress being used.
Divi Theme (+ Child Theme) and Builder 3.0 being used.

No cacheing plugin being used.

Answer (score 1):

The Divi theme has well-known issues when it comes to site search and results. Divi uses short-codes for post formatting, and some search plugins do not execute the short-codes - like a web browser does - but present search results from the database. So you will see unexecuted short-codes and other formatting coding in search results when using plugins that access the database for search results. This same issue occurs with other similar themes and many "page builder" plugins that also use short-codes for design and formatting.

The default WordPress search does not have this issue with Divi; but the default search engine does not provide results sorted by keyword, only by date, which is an issue when you want keyword relevancy in results, and/or live results, as with the Algolia plugin.

Comment: Hi there, I just wanted to add here that we apply 'the_content' filter before sending data to Algolia so shortcodes should be parsed. If you realize something is not working on that side, please open an issue here: github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-wordpress

Comment: Thanks  rayrutjes. Have opened an issue. Cheers.

Comment: Just to let you know that we are still waiting for the eleganttheme support to give us some insight here. We managed to get it working with the Visual Composer but not yet with the Divi builder. Feel free to reach to their support as well.

Comment: The answer from the theme authors was that there is no easy way to replace Divi builder's shortcodes programatically. As a consequence, there is now way to properly index content hidden behind those shortcodes.

Comment: "now a way to properly" or "no way to properly"?